# Kotlin - Dynamic Runtime Deconstructing in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is it be possible to create a method in Kotlin 1.5 to support dynamic object creation at runtime and support deconstruction like so:

```
val (A, B, C, D, E) = buildNodes("A,B,C,D,E")
```

The difference here is that we would need to create the methods component1() .. component5() dynamically at runtime.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html

Comment: How do you want to write the destructuring declaration dynamically?

Comment: By somehow not having to do it or abstracting it away. Is it possible to declare the operator at runtime through reflection or extensions?

Answer (score 2):

There is one problem with this. `componentX()` functions are used not only to get the value at runtime. They are also used to infer the type of destructured variables. You can dynamically choose in `buildNodes()` what will be the value of `A`, but you can't decide on its compile type dynamically.

So it really depends on what do you mean that these items are constructed dynamically. You can create items dynamically as long as their types are somehow predictable. For example, if your `buildNodes()` always returns only strings, then this is fine. In fact, you can return `List<String>` and it will work for at most 5 items. You can also create an interface and decide on the implementation at runtime. Or even make `buildNodes()` generic, so it returns different types depending on something. At the last resort, you can return `Any` and check the type of destructured items at the runtime.

But you can't expect that depending on the contents of the passed string, the `A` variable will change its compile type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my situation the type is known to be consistent and known at compile time for vars A,B, etc. I do see your point.